# How can I disable image loading in Awesomium?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, awesomium

How can I disable image loading in the browser Awesomium in offscreen rendering mode?

Comment: Is this a software development question or a question about the settings of an individual application?

Comment: This is a software development question. Awesomium is .Net and C++ web control library.  [link](http://www.awesomium.com)

Comment: Cheers; not heard of it before, wanted to check that it was relevant to the site (this question came up on my "review" list). You may want to ask on http://answers.awesomium.com/ too, as that seems to have quite an active audience too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can use ResourceInterceptor. Advantage: it can be switched without recreating WebSession + WebControl/WebView.

```
public class ResourceInterceptor : IResourceInterceptor
{
    public bool NoImages { get; set; }

    private static string[] _imagesFileTypes = { ".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".bmp" };

    public ResourceResponse OnRequest(ResourceRequest request)
    {
        string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(request.Url.ToString()).ToLower();

        if (NoImages && _imagesFileTypes.Contains(ext))
        {
            request.Cancel();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public bool OnFilterNavigation(NavigationRequest request)
    {
        return false;
    }
}


...

ResourceInterceptor ResInt = new ResourceInterceptor();
WebCore.ResourceInterceptor = ResInt;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can switch off loading of images when you create a WebSession:

`WebView.WebSession = WebCore.CreateWebSession(new WebPreferences(){LoadImagesAutomatically = false});`